# Android will run only on CA Root Certificates?

Tags: android, ssl

I have created self signed certificate and installed in a server.To enable https in android is it required ca root cerificate.? Android won't run in self signed certificates?

Comment: Most android browsers allow you to add exceptions for certificates. To use https from inside an app you are creating, you must add your CA in your device's trusted CAs. To do that, you may need root access or factory reset. I'm not sure this is the only way, but it was the only way a couple of years ago I had the same problem

Comment: Ok,we have to use only one certificate rite in client side(Android device) i.e is in bks format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned clearly say that `HttpURLConnection` won't work with a self signed certificate.

They also imply that you can create your own `TrustManager` as a workaround.